# how to save many data in pivot table in laravel

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, many-to-many, pivot-table

i want to save two data (qte and total) in pivot table, how can i do that

---

here my code

---

artical model

```
class Artical extends Model{

protected $table = 'artical';
protected $primaryKey = 'ida';
protected $fillable = [ 'num_art' , 'designation', 'unite','prix_unit',];}
```

---

devis model

```
class Devis extends Model{

protected $table = 'Devis';
protected $primaryKey = 'idd';
protected $fillable = ['type', 'lot', 'prix_total_avant_tax', 'tax_perse', 'tax_amount', 'prix_total_apre_tax', 'notes',];


public function articals()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Artical::class)->withPivot(['qte'])->withPivot(['total']);
}}
```

---

devis_artical table (pivot tavle)

[image]

---

store function

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $Devis = Devis::create($request->all());


    $articals = $request->input('articals', []);
    $quantité = $request->input('quantité', []);
    $total = $request->input('total', []);

    for ($product=0; $product < count($articals); $product++) {
    if ($articals[$product] != '') {
        $Devis->articals()->attach($articals[$product], ['qte'=> $quantité[$product]], ['total'=> $total[$product]]);
    }
}

    return redirect('/Devis');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the Laravel documentation - it is one of the best and good source for learning.

```php
class Devis extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'Devis';
    protected $primaryKey = 'idd';
    protected $fillable = ['type', 'lot', 'prix_total_avant_tax', 'tax_perse', 'tax_amount', 'prix_total_apre_tax', 'notes',];


    public function articals()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Artical::class)->withPivot('qte', 'total');
    }
}
```

[Laravel Docs - Eloquent Relationships - Retrieving Intermediate Table Columns](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#retrieving-intermediate-table-columns)

And then in controller

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $Devis = Devis::create($request->all());


    $articals = $request->input('articals', []);
    $quantité = $request->input('quantité', []);
    $total = $request->input('total', []);

    for ($product=0; $product < count($articals); $product++) {
        if ($articals[$product] != '') {
            $Devis->articals()->attach($articals[$product], [
                'qte'=> $quantité[$product], 
                'total'=> $total[$product]
            ]);
        }
    }

    return redirect('/Devis');
}
```

[Laravel Docs - Eloquent Relationships - Attaching Detaching](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#attaching-detaching)

Comment: than you mate @Donkarnash for your help, the problem solved